# UITextField NSString length problems while formatting NSString

Tags: iphone, if-statement, nsstring, uitextfield

I have been working on this for a few days now and I have some buzzy things going on with my textfields... and it's got to the point where I need to take a step back and hope someone with a fresh pair of eyes can shed light on the situation.

basically what I'm doing is formatting a 20 character string into sets of 5 as the user types after every 5th character a hyphen pops into the string, that works sweet.

I have a submit button that is not perusable until the 20th character is entered, this also works but where it gets CRAZY! is if you delete back one character the submit button still works.. then you delete back one more character and it doesn't work... I'm at a loss as my if statements conditions don't work like they should I specify == 23 characters and you have to hit one of the keys 24 times to get into that statement.. it makes no logical sense.

anyway if you could help me with the first question that would be great then if you have any ideas on the second question that would be great.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *separator = @"-";
    int seperatorInterval = 5; //how many chars between each hyphen
    NSString *originalString = [regTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:@""];


    if (textField.text.length == 23 && range.length == 0){
        return NO; // return NO to not change text
    }       
    if (![originalString isEqualToString:@""] && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSString *lastChar = [regTextField.text substringFromIndex:[regTextField.text length] - 1];
        int modulus = [originalString length] % seperatorInterval;

        if (![lastChar isEqualToString:separator] && modulus == 0) {
                regTextField.text = [regTextField.text stringByAppendingString:separator];
        }
    }
    [self validateTextFields];
    return YES; //Keep accepting input from the user
}

//Validating text field to see if Submit button can be pressed or not
-(IBAction) validateTextFields {
    NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", regTextField.text.length];
    NSLog(@"Starting %@", intString);
    if (regTextField.text.length < 22){
        [submitButton setEnabled:NO]; //enables submitButton
    } 
    else {
        regTextField.text = [regTextField.text substringToIndex:22];
        [submitButton setEnabled:YES]; //disables submitButton
    }
    intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", regTextField.text.length];
    NSLog(@"Done %@", intString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `=` sign in this if statement

```
if (regTextField.text.length <= 22){
```

or just change the number to 23 either way it should work

```
if (regTextField.text.length < 23){
```